# How to populate a "select" with datas from specifc table on database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, laravel-5.3

I'm developping a system in PHP and MySQL with Laravel 5.3. Well, I have a table, on database, that ws populated with a amount of brazilians cities and I need create a select option, in my view, that load the cities. But each city belongs to more than one group, and each groups has many cities. So how can I do this in my view? The easy, and bad, way can be (in the view) create a select and some if and else stetements. I want to do this dynamically and without contaminate the view page. How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you create a group; then, you display its related cities whenever someone select that group.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  The question that you've asked is too broad to be answered here.  Sounds like you need a tutorial on dealing with with `joins` .

Comment: I created a table group. There is a foreign key. But I don't know how can I put in the select the specifics cities when the user choose a specific group.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I can see that. I am new with database and I not thought about "Joins".